# Python script, twitter bot for retweeting specific tweets

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, tweepy

I made a Twitter Bot for retweeting, following and unfollowing people (when max reached), but when I thought that my bot was fully operational Twitter Blocked me.. That's because if wansn't checking if my bot already retweeted a tweet but I had a try/except block. So I was making a lot of api calls to retweet... I was wondering how I could check if I already retweeted this tweet ?
I thought of looking up every user of had retweeted the tweet and if my username was in it, passing to the next tweet, but it's not very effective. I can share my code, and feel free to ask for any clarification.
Thank you,
Kajpio
PS: I'm using tweepy to interact with the API !

Update, here is a part of my code, just the part checking for retweet:

```
loginToTwitter()
query = 'a string'  
tweet_cursor= tweepy.Cursor(api.search, query, result_type="recent").items()
print("Searching")
for tweet in tweet_cursor:
    tweetText = tweet.text.lower()
    if "rt" in tweetText:
        if tweet.retweeted == True: #It return me each time a false boolean but then I get the api.code 327 from twitter 
            print("already retweeted")
            continue
        try:
            api.retweet(tweet.id)
            print('Retweedted')
            time.sleep(2)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            if e.api_code == 327:
                print("Tried but tweet already Retweeted" )
            print(e)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            continue
```

Comment: "I can share my code" please do it

Comment: if you're using the REST APIs then yes, you will be calling a lot of retweets. Why not look at the streaming APIs (which tweepy can also handle)?

Comment: Updated status ! Aleks Andreev

Comment: @asongtoruin Could you explain me how I could use the streaming API with my bot ? Of what I understood of my research it's like an open request to twitter's server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if you have already retweeted a particular tweet by keeping track of of the tweet's id. Before you retweet, just check the tweet's id against your list (or database table) of id's. If the tweet your are retweeting is also a retweet of another tweet, you check that tweet's id by looking at the `retweet_status` field.

I don't think you will get blocked by retweeting the same tweet multiple times. In general, Twitter will not let you tweet the same tweet more than once in a 24 hour period. Twitter will return error code 187 instead. ([Twitter's error codes](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes).) You may have gotten blocked if you tweeted too frequently. Twitter doesn't specify a rate limit for status updates. If you do exceed their internal rate limit, you will receive a 403 HTTP status code, and then it is up to you to back off from your updates until you no longer receive a 403 code.

Comment: I just updated my question for better understanding of my question. The fact that I have a try/catch block, makes my bot doing a api request each time. I retweeted 20k tweets in one month and a half. The file would be huge :p I thought of that, I think it could work on a much smaller scale !

Comment: Twitter will let you tweet the same tweet after 24 hours. So, the file would only need to contain tweets that you tweeted within the last 24 hours. Simply remove tweets from the file after 24 hours.

Comment: The problem with your try/catch is that when Twitter sends you an error that is requiring you to stop tweeting for a while your code ignores the error and keeps tweeting. Then you get blocked.

Comment: But I just want to retweet a tweet. Is there an API call to check if I or a specific user (I would write my username) retweeted a tweet ? I did not get the thing with the 24 hours, if I retweet a tweet he will be retweeted for ever or until the user delete it.

Comment: No, there is no API call to check if someone retweeted a tweet.

Comment: Regarding the 24 hours...Twitter will not let you tweet the same thing more than one time in a 24-hour period. Twitter will not block you for this. Instead you will get an error code. Twitter *will* block you if you tweet too frequently, but before Twitter blocks you it will send you an error to warn you. Your try/catch is bad because it ignores this warning and then you get blocked.

Comment: Okey so I need to do a database with the tweets ids and the date. How would you this database ? By a dictionary (because we need just two values) ?

Comment: A dict would work. More robust would be a NOSQL database like CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

How many tweets are we talking about here? You could use an sqlite db to store the ID of tweets you have already retweeted. If there are too many tweets, you can clean the db of tweet IDs that you retweeted over 10 days ago or something, assuming you won't find the same tweet after 10 days?

Comment: I retweet giveaways, the number of tweets is huge and the database would be huge too. And some giveaways are ending after one month or so..